# Is there function that can be expanded as infinite power series with bounded positive coefficients？

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, power-series

Is there a rational function $F$ which may be expanded as power series with coefficients of unperiodical positive integers in such a form:

$$F(x)=\sum_0^{\infty}a_i x^i,\qquad a_i\in \mathcal{N} \cup \{0\},\quad\exists M\forall i,\space a_i \leq M.$$

Any unclear meaning may be clarified by comment and discussion.

Second question: Let $F$ be a function which may be expanded as power series with coefficients of unperiodical positive integers  as above. Prove that $F$ is transcendental (I guess a function with expansion of power series with coefficients of bounded unperiodical positive integers has to be a rational function or transcendental).

Comment: what does unperiodical mean exactly? Eventually unperiodical, or something else?

Comment: Don't the Taylor coefficients of a rational function always satisfy a linear recurrence relation? That together with boundedness should give you eventual periodicity.

Comment: @kartop_man eventually unperiodical

Comment: @AndreasBlass it is what I think, there is no such rational function.

Comment: The key ingredient is Kronecker's theorem: if $P \in {\bf Z}[X]$ is monic and all complex zeros satisfy $|z|\leq 1$ then those zeros are roots of unity.  Let $P$ be the denominator of $F$ and soon conclude that the power-series coefficients are periodic.

Comment: I agree with Andreas Blass: a bounded sequence of integer numbers, that satisfies an $n$-terms recurrence (linear or not) is necessarily eventually periodic (one may think it as a sequence $x_i=f(x_{i-1})$ in $\mathbb{Z}^n$)

Comment: I agree with AndreasBlass and @PietroMajer ... think of it as a sequence $x_i = f(x_{i-1})$ in a finite subset of $\mathbb Z^n$.  (Trying to do it with Kronecker's theorem, we need to note that it is not assumed that $F$ has integer coefficients nor that the denominator of $F$ is monic.  So these would have to be proved.)

Comment: The question specified integral (and positive) coefficients -- otherwise there are easy counterexamples like $1/(2-x)$.   Yes, it must be proved that this implies that the denominator has constant coefficient $\pm 1$ (not "monic" as I mistakenly wrote above: one must substitute $1/x$ for $x$ to make that work).

Comment: the second question is important，: Let F be a function which may be expanded as power series with coefficients of unperiodical positive integers as above. Prove that F is transcendental (I guess a function with expansion of power series with coefficients of bounded unperiodical positive integers has to be a rational function or transcendental）.

Comment: I think it is worth recalling a theorem of Christol, Kamae, Mendès-France and Rauzy (“Suites algébriques, automates et substitutions”, *Bull. SMF* **108** (1980), 401–419): a formal series $f = \sum a_i x^i \in \mathbb{F}_q[[x]]$ with coefficients in a finite field (with $q=p^r$ elements) is algebraic if and only if its coefficient $a_i$ can be computed by a finite automaton from the base $p$ expansion of $i$.

Comment: Now, an observation: if a sequence $(a_i)$ with values in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,M\}$ is not eventually periodic, then for all $p\gg 0$, it cannot be computed by a finite automaton from the base $p$ expansion of $i$, and hence, by the theorem quoted in my previous comment, $\sum a_i x^i$ is transcendental in $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$. So this doesn't solve the question, but at least it proves that all reductions of $F$ mod a sufficiently large prime are transcendental.

Comment: In particular, my last two comments seem to show that $F$ as in the question cannot be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$, because if it were then we could reduce the algebraic equation mod $p\gg 0$ and get a nontrivial algebraic equation over $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$, contradicting my previous comment. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen let me think about it. And why do you not post an answer to the question.

Comment: Because I'm not quite sure of myself, and I might not have the time to fill in the details.